# Can't print value of variable in screen field

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't see the value of the variable `i` (2424) in my screen form. How can I print the value in the designated screen field? This is the Python code I'm using:

```py
label0 = tk.Label(root, text='TOTAL RECORDS IN TABLE SONG: ')
label0.config(font=('helvetica', 12))
canvas1.create_window(210, 90, window=label0)
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                        'Server=MSI;'
                        'Database=MUSIC;'
                        'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT Count(*) FROM dbo.MUSIC_STG_MUSIC_SONGS')
for i in cursor:
        print(i)
entry1 = tk.Entry (root)
##canvas1.create_window(415, 90, window=entry1)
for item in range(1):
        canvas1.create_window(415, 90, i, window=entry1)
```

I tried to use several commands in the code, like `get("i")`, or `print(i)`.
`print(i)` works but puts the value `2424` in the Python Idle shell, and not in my screen field.

The variable `i` stands for the number of records in the table of songs.
This number of records is pulled out by the query.

But I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\PYTHON\00000_PROJECTS\MUSIC\MUSIC.py", line 181, in <lambda>
    edit.add_command(label ='12.6   COUNT SONGS PER MUSIC TYPE', command = lambda: checkrecordsmusictype())
  File "C:\PYTHON\00000_PROJECTS\MUSIC\MUSIC.py", line 391, in checkrecordsmusictype
    canvas1.create_window(415, 90, list(i), window=entry1)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2843, in create_window
    return self._create('window', args, kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2805, in _create
    return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "2424"

When i put the +str(i) after the line of text i get the following error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Label' and 'str'.
Thxs for your support Tim.
```

Comment: What do you think `i` represents in this line of code? `canvas1.create_window(415, 90, i, window=entry1)`? Do you think it's a coordinate? An object id? A tag?

Comment: Hi Bryan, First of all thanks for your comment. I is in this case a numerical variable with the value 0.

Comment: Why do you think you need to pass it in? What do you think that number represents?

Comment: You need to add that to the `label0` string.  `text="TOTAL RECORDS IN TABLE SONG: "+str(i)`.